# Can some explain the java code given here?

Tags: java, class

code - job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);

what does it mean by passing param as Text.class? whey .class is required.

Comment: `Text.class` is an object in Java that represents the `Text` class. The function obviously expects a class as an argument.

Comment: Try it without the `.class`, see what happens. FYI, this is called a [class literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2).

Comment: What it means is that you should open up the book and learn at least the fundamentals of the language.  You cannot learn a language one syntax element at a time by asking questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

`Text.class` is literal that allow you to reference to `java.lang.Class` objects.

It is roughly same as if you do `Class.forName("yourpackage.Text")`